# Show multiple device in one location on map

Tags: layout

I've wrote a program to manage our devices. As you see below, we show device status on the map plus junction traffic for entrance and there is ability to access configuration and reports by right click on its icon.

At first there is only one device type, but now we got another one. The other device is a special sensor controller and is exactly on the current location, so how would I show the new device status and way to access it.

[image]

The map is a simple picture.
I have a little difficulty about tag selection.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can solve your problem if you read this:

[How can I represent multiple pins at the same location on a map?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/75139/how-can-i-represent-multiple-pins-at-the-same-location-on-a-map)

Its the same problem even though right now you only need to display a maximum of 2 devices.

Comment: +1. Furthermore you can add OnHover action that will display a balloon (tooltip) presenting all your devices in the particular location with the possibility for further action (getting info, browsing, setting, etc.)